# IIS windows deny the first url segment if it's more than 50 character

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewriting

I use IIS windows server 2012 with some Url rewrites rule.
My problem is that if the first "Url segment" is more than 50-60 digits I have the CPU that goes up to 100%.
So since my running URL's are lower than 50-60 digits how can I stop processing if the first URL segment is >50 char?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by  "Url segment" ?

Comment: http://www.example.com/first_url_segment/second_url_segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will abort all requests if your first url segment is more than 50 symbols

```
<rule name="Abort if first segment more than 50" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(\w{50})" />
    <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of: ^(\w{50})

Comment: Sure, this regeex `^(\w{50})` will match "a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character" which is more than 50 symbols.

Comment: Is it include the -(hyphen)? if not how can I put in this regex? Thankyou

Comment: Sure, regex with hyphen is `^([\w-]{50})`